# Is there any update on the Availability of Event Horizon Telescope Images?

Tags: radio-astronomy, sagittarius-a, event-horizon-telescope

There has been no news on the obvious public channels from the EHT project since last (Northern) summer. Does anyone have more information on when any results from the April 2017 run might be released?

A secondary question is has the data from the April 2018 run been successfully gathered? I know they have to wait for Antarctic spring to ship the hard drives from the South pole, but that should have arrived a couple of months ago.

Comment: I've been to a EHT talk last month, and it seems the results from 2017 are still embargoed / not finalized.

Comment: I guess a picture would prove the existence of a black hole.
What else could we learn from a decent picture of one?
My hats off to those that have been trying so hard to do this.

Comment: @JamesLancaster The picture would be evidence about what happens in the immediate vicinity of a moderately active black hole. We have theories about how this should work -- thin and thick accretion disks and so on, but only rather indirect data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Today, April 10th 2019](https://eventhorizontelescope.org/latest), there was a press conference where finally an image of M87 was released:

> [image]
>
> Scientists have obtained the first image of a black hole, using Event Horizon Telescope observations of the center of the galaxy M87. The image shows a bright ring formed as light bends in the intense gravity around a black hole that is 6.5 billion times more massive than the Sun. This long-sought image provides the strongest evidence to date for the existence of supermassive black holes and opens a new window onto the study of black holes, their event horizons, and gravity. Credit: Event Horizon Telescope Collaboration

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2019/jan/11/scientists-close-to-capturing-first-image-of-black-hole-at-the-centre-of-the-milky-way) neewpaper article appears to reflect new information from the project.

> The observations, by the Event Horizon Telescope, are expected to be unveiled in March . . .
>
> The team is in the final phase of reviewing data that was gathered in 2017 . . .

Nothing there about the 2018 data.